# XHR Post Request Not Working in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to do a simple post request to a Node page (all on the same domain, localhost) from a client-side XMLHttpRequest. I am using the npm module 'xhr'. The post request is detected, though the req.query object is empty.

Here is my client-side request:

```
xhr.post({
    body: JSON.stringify({ test: 'abc' }),
    timeout: 5000,
    uri: '/xhr/post-here',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
}, function(err, res, body) {});
```

Here is my node post controller:

```
router.post('/xhr/post-here', function(req, res) {
    console.log('req.query: ' + JSON.stringify(req.query));

    if (req.query.test) {
       res.status(200).send({ valid: true });
    } else {
        res.status(400).end();
    }
});
```

The console.log in the post handler is showing that the req.query object is empty, even though I sent it in the body. However, if I attempt this request in Postman, req.query gets the correct parameters.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: req.query is for `/path?param=value`. You should fetch `req.body` on the server side.

Comment: @OlegMeleshko I tried using the npm module 'body-parser' to get req.body, though it was always undefined. The weird thing is, if I attempt this request in Postman, it goes through just fine.

Comment: @KiaShakiba `body-parser` works perfectly, did you use it as middleware in your node app? Try to read `body-parser` documentation attentively

Comment: @MysterX oh, it appears that I one of my other middleware functions was ruining the request. I applied body-parser and it worked perfectly. Thanks!